# How to simply add album covers to an iTunes playlist?

Tags: macbook-pro, itunes

I would like to create a Playlist folder into which I could put album covers, without showing all the cuts within, since I play a classical recording as an individual entity. This would simplify finding an album without having to wade through all of the movements within a recording.

Answer (score 1):

Create your playlist, then select View As > Albums.

[image]